# Laravel Valet Share Error: "dial tcp [...] no such host"

Tags: laravel, nginx, ngrok, laravel-valet, valet

I just installed Laravel Valet. Everything works perfectly, except for the site sharing function.

After typing

```
valet share
```

Terminal returns the following output, right before Ngrok opens:

```
grep: /Users/myname/.config/valet/Nginx/myurl*: No such file or directory
```

Ngrok gives me a public URL, but my browser returns a page with title **Failed to complete tunnel connection** and error message **dial tcp: lookup myurl.test on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host**.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have a look at this one, it is really detailed troubleshooting: https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/695

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I think my problem is quite different?

Answer (score -3):

*Solution for laragon*

If you are using any VPN, then turn it off and then reload laragon.